# d3 mercator projection measuring distance (or converting) in meters

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, mercator

So I'm currently using this to calculate the area of a polygon using mercator projection in d3

[Calculating Polygon Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285134/calculating-polygon-area)

The problem is I need to convert it to meters or kilometers. I'm not really sure what formula to use as I think it changes depending on the zoom level correct? Can anybody point me to the right direction to get this formula correct?

I'm actually thinking of switching to leaflet just to get the area. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [`d3.geo.area()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#area) to compute the area and then convert to meters?

Comment: right, but how does one convert from pixel to meters (or km)?

Comment: That function computes the area in steradians.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to convert a steradian to meters/km. Only to square degrees which is new to me. Do you have any links where I can read more about it?

Comment: There's more information on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_degree