# Determine if square cell is inside polygon

Tags: geometry, polygon, voronoi, point-in-polygon

[image]

For instance, I want the grid cells (squares) inside or partially inside polygon #14 to be associated with #14. Is there an algorithm that will compute if a square is inside a polygon efficiently?

I have the coordinates of the edges that make up the polygon.

Comment: What's known about the polygon, if anything? Is it always convex? Or it can be arbitrary? (A Voronoi cell by any chance?)

Comment: Yes, it is a Voronoi cell.

Comment: Is the Voronoi the result of clustering process? More specifically, do you have coordinates of cluster centers and a similarity measurement?

Comment: No, it's just generated from random points on a canvas. [Here](http://www.raymondhill.net/voronoi/rhill-voronoi.html) is the implementation I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, this is an implementation of [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) in JavaScript, that takes a set of 2-d points (called `sites`) and returns a structure containing data for a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) computed for this points. It returns polygons in a list called `cells`. It seems to use [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) as measurement. If it's true we know that polygons are always convex (see *Formal definition* section in [Voronoi wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)).

Now, these are options to solve this problem (hard to simple):

**1. Polygon Clipping**:

1. Form a polygon for the square.
2. [Find its intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection) with all cells.
3. [Calculate area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285134/calculating-polygon-area) of this intersections.
4. Find the largest intersection.

**2- Point in Polygon**:

You also can simply find the cell that center of the square lies inside it. [Ray casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) is a robust PIP algorithm. Although there's a simpler approach for convex polygons (see Convex Polygons section [here](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/)).

**3. Distance Between Points**:

I if you know the `site` associated to each `cell` then you just need to calculate distance between center of square to all `sites`. Regardless of what [distance measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) you use to compute the Voronoi, the center point of square lie inside the `cell` that distance of it's associated `site` is minimum, since this is actually the idea for partitioning the plane in a Voronoi diagram.

---

**Exceptions:**

- First approach is computationally expensive but most accurate. Second and third options work fine in most cases, however, there are exceptions that they fail to decide correctly:

[image]

- Second and third are pretty much alike, but the down side of PIP is cases where point lies on edges of the polygon that cost you more overhead to detect.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up implementing ray casting.